# how to use punjabi font in the android application?

Tags: android, fonts, textview

hi
 i want to develop an application in which i Want to use punjabi text. But my emmulator does not show Punjabi text. Is there any api or something else so that my emulator can show the punjabi text or suggest me any other way to implement punjabi language in my application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "does not show"? Is it invisible? Corrupted ASCII text? Do you get an error message? A screenshot might help, you could have a different problem than you think.

Comment: hi Nicholas my question is that, I want to display the Punjabi text in Emulator as it shows me box, box ... which is not readable, So please guide me the solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: Please check first any one can ask this type of question or not.. duplication question.

Comment: @AviKumarManku can you give me punjabi font for android application

Comment: @rohit sorry buddy i do not have any punjabi fonts i asked this question for my friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom TrueType fonts by copying the .ttf file into your projects's 'assets' folder.

Then in your application you can use the font like this;

```
final Typeface customF = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "custom.ttf");
final TextView textV = (TextView) findViewById(...);
textV.setTypeface(customF);
```

However i've had so many problems trying to use TrueType fonts so you might want to do some real life testing with your (pubjabi) font.

Comment: Yes, I already done with this concept but still it doesnt show me punjabi text properly somewhere it is showing boxes instead of punjabi alphabets.

Comment: Thanx for the help Zeropage i have tried it but at some places it shows the text and at some places it shows the Box images.And I tried to run it on my device but it failed to install and showed the error cannot parse the application

Answer (score 3):

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "bulara_5.ttf");  
text.setTypeface(font);  
text.setText("ਪੰਜਾਬੀ");
```

This worked for me on non rooted phone OSv 2.1

Link for font file I used: http://homepage.ntlworld.com/paul-grosse/bulara.zip

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that android 2.3 supports the punjabi font. Hence you see those boxes.

Follow [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3029) to know when your favourite language will be supported. I've heard that Samsung android devices support *some* Indian regional fonts.

Comment: Hi reno thaks for help so is there any way like jar file or api file to support punjabi language on emulator

Comment: I don't know about the emulator, [check this out](http://arvinderkang.com/2009/12/03/gurmukhi-on-mobile/)