# how to show punjabi text in my android application?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use punjabi font in the android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199813/how-to-use-punjabi-font-in-the-android-application)

hii...

I  am making an android based application in which I want to show punjabi font on view. 
Anyone know how Can I represent punjabi font in android application. Please help me.

Thanks alot.