# how to transform Unicode characters to a different font?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, ms-word

I was able to transform sinhala Unicode characters to symbols by just copying those characters into MS word and changing the font to TIMES NEW ROMAN, The letters are in the link image;

[image: Sinhala unicode letters]

sequence of symbols and letters  =  fnda, rduqj - .Kl rduqj

But now I can't changed those Unicode characters into sequence of symbols and letters. Every time I paste those characters it doesn't allow me to change to another font type. How can I make it changeable or is there a better way of getting that sequence of letters?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Not 100% but i need those character sequence in order to develop an android application which doesn't need any unocde character installation previuosly.

Comment: If the font you used renders "fnda, rduqj - .Kl rduqj" as those characters then you won't be able to view that sensibly in *any* "Latin" alphabet font, without doing Unicode properly.

Comment: What you have *isn't* Unicode, it's just a weird font. You might be able to install and use that font with your Android app directly though.

Comment: Thanks for the replies..I'll try out that..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199813/how-to-use-punjabi-font-in-the-android-application/7500422#7500422 may be of interest if you want to use a custom font with your application.