# how to write in punjabi in the ListView in android?

Tags: android

i have used the punjabi font anmollipi in my android application. it is working good when i read it from a file using buffere reader but i am not able to show the punjabi in the ListView. any suggestions

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use punjabi font in the android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199813/how-to-use-punjabi-font-in-the-android-application)

Comment: I should have flagged as well instead of answering, anyway.

Comment: Your listview cell will contains textview .Did you mention typeface in each of TextView with punjabi font ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom adapter like this -

```
    public class CustomUsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    public CustomUsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
        super(context, 0, users);
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        User user = getItem(position);    
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Kokila.ttf"); 
        tvName.setTypeface(type);
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        tvName.setText(user.name);
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

here we used `item_user`, which is layout to your each line. Like this -

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0033"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

We used this code to set the typeface,

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Kokila.ttf"); 
txtView.setTypeface(type);
```

and you will have to put your font file in a new folder with name "fonts".

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> readAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,read);
  setListAdapter(readAdapter); ::::here the read is a string array containing the values, which i want to show in punjabi

Comment: This is your first time on StackOverFlow, so I am helping you to this length. Read here -http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how to ask good question, and how much effort one should put before asking a question. Welcome onboard.

Comment: ok thanks Darpan, i will take care of that next time i ask a question